# Get STDOUT into a variable

Tags: batch-file, email, dos

Im using [sendemail](http://freshmeat.net/projects/sendemail/) in a batch file. At the end of sending an email it replys with a message of succses or failure. For example

```
Jan 10 00:46:54 villa sendemail[456]: Email was sent successfully!
```

Is it possible to capture this message into a variable for processing?

Thx

Answer (score 16):

Yes, you need to execute sendmail through the for loop:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('[sendmail command line]') do (
    set VAR=%%a
)
```

After this runs, VAR will be set to the last line that sendmail output. You can then do processing on that line

```
for /f "tokens=5,* delims= " %%a in (%VAR%) do (
    if "%%b"=="Email was sent successfully!" (
        echo SUCCESS
        exit /b 0
    ) else (
        echo FAILURE
        exit /b 1
    )
)
```

Comment: Notice to myself: start looking for such things on Stackoverflow instead of google.

Comment: what about a command line like `strings %1 -t d | grep -e "[0-9]\{1,3\}"`? (tihs one with unxutils, but potentially with windows-only programs)

Comment: Thanks. This can be ran in cmd.exe outside of a BAT file as one command: `for /f %a in ('type file.txt') do (set VAR=%a)`. DO NOT do this: `for /f %a in ('type file.txt') do ( set VAR=%a )` (VAR = contents of file.txt plus one space character); don't do it unless you want a space at the end.

Answer (score -1):

normally, you just use the for loop to capture the output. see [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/for.php)  notes 4. (and search internet for more)