# WIndows batch analogue for unix shell command substitution

Tags: shell, batch-file, windows-shell

Is there any analogue for unix command substitution shell expansion? Like

```
> cmd1 `cmd2 -opt1 -opt2`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK You can't do that directly, but you can use soultion with for loop, similar to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033338/get-stdout-into-a-variable).