# Return a value from perl script into a batch file

Tags: perl

Is it possible to return a value from a perl script, such as an integer, into a batch or cmd file?

I was thinking like this:

```
set RESULT=0
set COUNT=0

ascript.pl > %RESULT%

%COUNT% += %RESULT%

otherscript.pl > %RESULT%

%COUNT% += %RESULT%
```

Comment: Just `print` something in the Perl script.

Comment: To use this the way you want, you would need some ability like bash's command substitution. Here is a link to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033338/get-stdout-into-a-variable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323292/windows-batch-assign-output-of-a-program-to-a-variable